# Difference between boost::unique_lock and boost::upgrade_lock?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am new to threading concept in C++ . I Just wanted to know few things: **How is a `boost::unique_lock` different from `boost::upgrade_lock`?**

How actually an exclusive ownership differ from upgrade ownership.

Maybe one can say exclusive ownership is thread safe but not upgrade ownership,
       in that case i would like to know how can an upgrade ownership can be harmful if 
       it can be? I want to know what is that `upgrade_lock` allows or not allows that 
       `unique_lock` does except exclusive lock thing. Not providing exclusive lock by 
       `upgrade_lock` makes it similar to `shared_lock` or what and if so then how is it 
       different from `shared_lock`?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html)?

Comment: I am going through http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html But could not find the detailed explanation of difference between two .

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I want to know what is that upgrade_lock allows or not allows that unique_lock does except exclusive lock thing. Not providing exclusive lock by upgrade_lock makes it similar to shared_lock or what and if so then How is it different from shared_lock ?

Comment: Exactly that is answered in the SharedLockable requirements. An `upgrade_lock` is normally a `shared_lock`, but can be upgraded to a `unique_lock`.

Comment: @Xeo yes upgrade_lock can be upgraded to uniue_lock by upgrade_yo_unique_lock . so why do we need shared_lock is that because shared_lock cant be upgrade to unique_lock ? Is that the only thing ?

Comment: read http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/mutexes/locking.html#Upgrade

Answer (score 7):

The difference between `upgrade_lock` and `unique_lock` is simple. An instance of `unique_lock` is acquiring a full exclusive ownership of a `shared_mutex`. This means that no one else can get any type of ownership while the `unique_lock` is alive.

Unlike the `unique_lock` an instance of `upgrade_lock` is acquiring an upgrade ownership that exclusive only amongst threads trying to get the same upgrade ownership. All other threads that try to get a shared ownership could acquire it with no conflict until the `upgrade_lock` is upgraded to unique (with an instance of `upgrade_to_unique_lock`).

The `upgrade_lock` is useful when some of threads can be readers only and will not try to promote itself to writers. Otherwise (all readers may try to become writers at some point) `upgrade_lock` will operate as `unique_lock`.

Answer (score 6):

> @Xeo yes upgrade_lock can be upgraded to uniue_lock by
>   upgrade_yo_unique_lock . so why do we need shared_lock is that because
>   shared_lock cant be upgrade to unique_lock ? Is that the only thing ?

Yes.

`shared_mutex` exists **only** to supply the functionality of traditional read/write mutexes.  Some clients will be understandably leery of a mutex changing lock-modes from one to another, and yet still need the traditional functionality of a rw/mutex.  This is the role of `shared_mutex`.

Other clients will look at `shared_mutex` and say:  I want more.  I want to sometimes atomically upgrade my ownership from shared to exclusive.  And this is the role of `upgrade_mutex`.  `upgrade_mutex` is not better than `shared_mutex`, nor vice-versa.  It is simply another tool in the toolbox.